# How to speed up MATLAB codes?

Tags: performance, matlab

As great as MATLAB is as a mathematical language, its speed is not as fast as one like it to be. I am wondering what are the general practices to speed up running a MATLAB code? For example I know that if instead of running for loops one can do computations in vector/matrix format s/he will see speedup in running the code.

I am wondering what are other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might begin reviewing some ways to begin thinking about vectorization [here](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/~vincent/matlabindexrepmat.html).
After that, the PDF given [here](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/doc/mtt/), even though incomplete, provides many Matlab idioms that give good performance.

Comment: The first link is instructive, but somewhat obsolete. Use `bsxfun` instead of `repmat`

Comment: Ouch I confirm the links are dead. I'll figure out what to do about it. Looks like other people voted more on the other answer anyway

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few basic performance tips:

1. Learn to use the profiler to understand which parts of your
   computation are slow
2. Limit the amounts of expensive function calls via vectorization
3. Preassign arrays instead of growing them in loops
4. Use multithreaded functions (such as `bsxfun`)
5. Use the latest version of Matlab - there have
   been tremendous performance gains over the last 5 years
6. Use the parallel toolbox for multicore and/or GPU processing
7. Use efficient algorithms
8. Use Java or C/C++ code where appropriate (though the speed-up can be disappointing)

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing a lot of easily-parallelizable operations, `parfor` will automatically parallelize your `for` loops: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: Just keep in mind that in some particular conditions `parfor` loops can be even slower than normal `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Lightspeed.

I have recently been through the frustrating process of installing Tom Minka's Lightspeed on my Mac. Along the way I learnt a few hard lessons worth sharing with other Mac users.
My system has the following specifications
OS X version 10.8.5
Xcode version 4.6.3
Matlab version 2011a

1) Make sure that Lightspeed is installed on a path with NO spaces in its name.  I made the mistake of putting it inside "Library/Application Support/Matlab" which caused me endless trouble.  In particular, it led to the same  issue reported by Tomer Levinboim (levinboim.blogspot.co.nz) with the added problem that his fixes did not fully resolve the problem!

2) Read Michel Valstar's notes "Compiling Matlab Mex Files on a Mac" and install the recommended patch from Mathworks  ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94092). This patch applies all the needed flag/option  changes that Levinboim identifies.

3) Change the line options.COMPFLAGS in the install_lightspeed.m file inside the lightspeed folder to point to:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk

4) In Matlab check that the current path  points at the Lightspeed folder.  Run the command install_lightspeed.  If successful run test_lightspeed. You should now have a working version of Lightspeed!

5) Path settings persist between sessions so the startup.sh approach suggested in the Read Me appears  to be unnecessary on a Mac. However, if you wish to go down that track,  first read:
[Where is startup.m supposed to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531877/where-is-startup-m-supposed-to-be) 
http://obasic.net/set-your-customized-startup-file-for-matlab .

Answer (score 0):

I just found this here: [Writing Fast MATLAB Code](http://optlab.mcmaster.ca/~yzinchen/fast-matlab-code.pdf).
by Pascal Getreuer and this here: [Lightspeed Toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/). Great stuff...