# Where is startup.m supposed to be?

Tags: matlab

I've been chasing the answer to this question in the MATLAB documentation for a long time...

For example, at the bottom of

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/changing-the-startup-folder.html

it says

> Use the startup.m file to specify the startup folder...

...which is plainly absurd, since elsewhere the documentation says that `startup.m` is to be found in the so-called "startup folder".  So therefore there's no way for this file to specify where this folder should be.

Etc., etc., etc.  This sort of circularity *pervades* everything I've found in the docs on `startup.m`.

What I want to know is: can I or can't I customize the location of the "startup folder" in a way that is persistent, and if so, where is this persistent information stored?

Comment: I totally agree about the circularity and I guess it comes from OS diversity! You can submit feedback/request for update on the docs (it is effective) by answering "NO" to *"Was this topic helpful?"* at the bottom right corner of each doc page.

Note also that **Specifying Startup Options in the MATLAB Startup File** says to *"Place the startup.m file in the default or current startup folder, which is where MATLAB first looks for it..."*. In a sense, there is a default startup folder returned by `userpath` and from there you can redirect somewhere else (or use the shortcut options if Win OS).

Comment: to add to @OlegKomarov: you can test where the startup.m file is by calling `which startup.m` (works btw on every function/file on the path). If you're trying to change things, this is a quick check to see if your changes were as intended.

Comment: Just installed matlab on ubuntu 18.04.  It seems to add $(USER)/Document/MATLAB in the path.  If that is a general case, then it seems make sense to put startup.m there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best method, I find, is this. Let's say you want MATLAB to start up in `mystartupdir`, and you've placed `startup.m` in that directory.

On Windows, make a shortcut icon to MATLAB, then right-click on it and select `Properties`. Edit the field `Start In`. Now, use this icon whenever you want to start MATLAB.

On other platforms, you can run MATLAB with the `-sd` flag to specify the startup directory:

`matlab -sd mystartupdir`

If you don't specify a startup directory, MATLAB will use the default specified by the `userpath` command. You can place your `startup.m` file there.

Comment: Actually, the `-sd mystartupdir` seems to be available *only* on Windows systems.  I have not been able to find an equivalent for it on Mac or Linux.

Comment: Also if you use `-useStartupFolderPref` option, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 14):

According to [this page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html#brlkmbe-1) in the docs, you should create your own `startup.m` in the "startup directory" which, if you follow the link, leads to [this page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html) explaining the definition of "startup directory" in this context.

You can retrieve this "startup directory" with the `userpath` function which returns, on my system:

```
>> userpath

ans =

C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\MATLAB;
```

Personally, I just set the "Start In" in the shortcut to whatever I want - but obviously this won't work if you're not on Windows; if you're not on Windows or prefer not to rely on the shortcut you should create a `startup.m` with a call to `cd` in whatever directory `userpath` returns.

The docs also say you can modify the `userpath` function, if you so desire, or the `matlabrc.m` file in `matlabroot/toolbox/local` (but you can only do the latter if you're a MathWorks engineer or a system administrator, otherwise MathWorks will rain fiery hell down on you from above, or something...).

Comment: So to create a startup.m in the 'right' place, type: `cd userpath` followed by `edit startup.m` and confirm that you want to create it.

Comment: *"The docs also say you can modify the `userpath` function"*: Sorry for this belated request, but upon revisiting this answer, I can't find where in the docs it says that one can modify the `userpath` function.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @kjo, to modify the userpath location, supply your desired path as an argument to the function. For example, `userpath('/home/MYUSERNAME/foo/matlab')`

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X, you may put your `startup.m` file in `/matlabrootfolder/toolbox/local/`.  For example, this path might look like the following for Matlab 2012: `/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/toolbox/local/`.

To prevent the file from being removed after upgrading Matlab, you may use a symlink to the file.  If your startup file is stored at `$HOME/myDir/startup.m`, for example (in Bash):

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/toolbox/local/
ln -s ~/myDir/startup.m .
```

Reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a pointer for Lx users (as confused as I was at first...). I work on Debian based boxes, but the same should apply to the CentOS system lineup, etc.

- Check that after install you do have the directory/ies: `~/.matlab/<yr_release(s)>`
  *Note that you may have several releases there as is my case. `matlab` actually permits that.*
- Create `~/.matlab/startup.m`
   *Incidentally I also created my directory `Workspace` there. That's completely optional*
- In your Matlab window's Home tab find the menu iten/icon `Set Path`, click on it and add a "matlab search path" with the button Add folder top left. Add `~/.matlab` as a new search path. Change should take effect immediately.
- Restart Matlab to check that the content of `~/.matlab/startup.m` is correctly taken into account at launch time.

I hate GUIs... I thought you might want to know ;-)  HTH.

Comment: If you hate GUIs, you might like to know that the `addpath` command followed by the `savepath` command gives you the same effect as your third bullet, without needing to enter the graphical path manager :)

Comment: The key point here is that your `startup.m` should be in your Matlab's PATH.

Answer (score 1):

As read in http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/matlab-startup-folder.html#buj_13n :

> Changing the Startup Folder
>
> Starting in R2014b, you can change the startup folder using the
>   General Preferences panel. On the Home tab, in the Environment
>   section, click Preferences. Select MATLAB > General. Choose an option
>   for the Initial working folder.
>
> By default, the initial working folder is set to Location based on
>   MATLAB startup rules.

I wish it did not involve the graphical desktop interface, though. By looking closely in the file `matlab.setting`, which under Linux should lie in `~/.matlab/<your_release>/`, you can find the lines

```
<key name="UserPath">
    <string>
        <value><![CDATA[<some_directory>]]></value>
    </string>
</key>
```

where you can certainly specify manually the startup directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me (I'm using Linux) it worked to put the "startup.m" to the home directory. Apparently, the home directory is by default on the matlab path. Strangely, it also worked when I put the "startup.m" into a newly created "matlab" (must be all lower-case) folder in the home directory. Let me know whether it also works on your system.