# How to set a folder as Current folder for every startup of Matlab?

Tags: macos, matlab

I would like to set the folder `/Users/ALJI/MATLAB` as a default current folder for Matlab. I mean on every start up Matlab should point to this folder. is it possible ? is there a way on Mac OS X ?

I am using `Matlab r2009b` on `Mac OS X Snow Leopard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it.

You edit a file named `startup.m` in `/matlabrootfolder/toolbox/local` and I add `cd /Users/ALJI/MATLAB`.

It worked, hope this help :)

Answer (score 10):

Easier: You can see the default path by typing

```
userpath
```

If you create a variable named for example NewPath and assign the path you want to set as default:

```
NewPath = 'Users/You/Desktop/Projects';
```

you can then call :

```
userpath(NewPath);
```

restart matlab and the trick is done.

Comment: i dont' know if those commands work in release 2009b, you should try. I think it is better than to create a startup file, which is a good idea if you want to execute multiple instructions, like change path, declare variables and so on... since you only have to change path i would avoid the startup.m. Maybe the fact that matlab has to search for the startup.m file and execute it, makes the directory change slower.

Comment: Nice solution, though I don't think performance is a relevant factor here it seems indeed more elegant than my suggestion. Note that this assumes that you don't need the current default folder in the search path.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I didn't think about that assumption but it's quite important. I tried (on my 2010 macbook pro with R2013a) both with userpath function and startup.m: with the startup.m matlab opens on the "old" current folder and after a while changes dir to the "new" current folder(in the previous comment i was trying to point out that) while with the userpath matlab opens right on the new directory. No big difference but it may matter for someone =) as solution i would use userpath to set the new current folder and a startup file to add other directories(with addpath func).

Answer (score 2):

Defining actions that will be done each time you start matlab can be done in a very fast and easy way.

When you start matlap type:

```
edit startup
```

If it does not exist, create it. The commands in this file will be ran on every startup of matlab.

In your case you may also want to check `help cd` for instructions on changing the directory programmatically.

Comment: if I do `edit startup` it will create a file `startup.m` on the current folder ... is it the right place to put it ?

Comment: @ALJIMohamed That should do the trick, if the current folder is not a desirable location you can try whether it still works if you put it somewhere else in the searchpath. (try `path`). You may also want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531877/where-is-startup-m-supposed-to-be)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `startup` as [answered by @Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710563/2586922), there's also the [`matlabrc` file](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/matlabrc.html). That's what you should use if you need the setup to apply to *all users*:

> On multiuser or networked systems, system administrators can put messages, definitions, or other code that applies to all users in their matlabrc.m file.
>
> The file matlabrc.m invokes the startup.m file, if it exists on the search path MATLAB uses.
>
> Individual users should use the startup.m file to customize MATLAB startup. The matlabrc.m file, located in the matlabroot/toolbox/local folder, is reserved for system administrators