# How to change current folder in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have tried these methods, but all of them didn't work:

1 pereference->general->initial working folder -> I change to my folder, but didn't work

2 setpath->add my folder on the top of folder,didn't work

3 userpath(myPath);

When I restart the icon in desktop, it always show this direction:

> ..\Polyspace\R2019b\bin

Comment: This is extremely windows specific

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710506/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of them didn't work
open the Matlab icon's properties and change shortcut -> start in